# exec.Command get error `exit status 0x80041017` which run successfully in CMD

Tags: go, cmd, wmic

Code in Go

```golang
out, err := exec.Command("wmic", "computersystem", "where", "name=\"%computername%\"", "call", "rename", "name", "newname").CombinedOutput()

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("err: ", err)
    fmt.Println("out: ", string(out))
}
```

error and output(`err:` and`out:`  are added by me):

```
err:  exit status 0x80041017
out:  Node - S
ERROR:        
Description = Invalid query
```

But run directly in CMD successfully:

```bash
wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" rename newname
```

```
Executing (\\S\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name="S")->rename()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the `os/exec` documentation:

> On Windows, processes receive the whole command line as a single string and do their own parsing. Command combines and quotes Args into a command line string with an algorithm compatible with applications using CommandLineToArgvW (which is the most common way). Notable exceptions are msiexec.exe and cmd.exe (and thus, all batch files), which have a different unquoting algorithm. In these or other similar cases, you can do the quoting yourself and provide the full command line in SysProcAttr.CmdLine, leaving Args empty.

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("wmic")
cmdLine := `computersystem where name="$computername" rename ` + newName
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{CmdLine: "/c " + os.ExpandEnv(cmdLine)}
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput() // Of course Run or Output
```